# how can i make sure that the user inputs a string containing only numbers, operators, and letter Q?

Tags: python

I can't seem to find how to keep the user constrained to using real numbers and the letter Q as the variable. (started learning Python this morning)

```
astr = 0
while True:
        astringfunctionMB = raw_input('please enter MB equation in terms of Q e.i 95-.5*Q : ' ) 
        if ( float(astringfunctionMB) or "Q" in astringfunctionMB):
              print "Please try again"
              #else if 
        else:
             break
             astr = astringfunctionMB
```

Comment: you should probably use regular expressions.

Comment: Your title says "numbers, operators", your text says "only real numbers".  Which is it?

Comment: Do you need only to check that the string contains numbers, operators and  Q or also (as i suppose) that it is a valid expression? (e.g. "1Q******" contains only numbers Q and operators but it isn't a valid expression)

Comment: oops typo. i meant to say both operators and real numbers

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of ways of doing this; I would either use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re

...

if re.match(r'^[\dQ+\-*/.]$', astringfunctionMB):
    ...
```

*(see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iW6cU0/3) for testing)* or create a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) of valid characters to test against:

```
import string

VALID_CHARS = set(string.digits + 'Q+-*/.')

...

if astringfunctionMB and all(char in VALID_CHARS for char in astringfunctionMB):
    ...
```

Note, however, that these don't *necessarily* mean that the user's input is a valid expression, just that it contains only the valid characters. For a more robust validation, you will need to write something to parse their input into an appropriate form, and see whether or not that can be run on whatever they type.

Comment: okay almost there! thanks!.. One question. How can i get this to work for all numbers? lets say user inputs 3.56*Q

Comment: @AleksChkadua what makes you think that doesn't already work?

Comment: I was wrong. It kept giving me a name error but the third time i checked it went away. Haha. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need a python expression in `aStringFunctionMB` you can evaluate it in a controlled namespace and catch exceptions:

```
try:
 eval(aStringFunctionMB, {}, {"Q": 1})
 astr = aStringFunctionMB
except (NameError, SyntaxError):
 print "Please try again"
```